# Sending buttons in email in c#

Tags: c#, html, api, outlook, gmail

I want to send  two buttons in email. On clicking of that buttons user should be able to Approve or Reject approval. It should work on gmail as well as outlook. I am not sure if web api will work.  I am using c# for sending email. Please share any idea.

Comment: You can't send a button in an email, you can send two links that send different requests to your API though.

Comment: Well, if your email sending software gives you the facility of sending HTML email, then you can do that.  You may find the links blocked by the user's email client though

Comment: From where are you sending this email?  From something like a server app, or from an email client?  If the latter, then I'm pretty sure that the GMail client and the Outlook client will do things differently

Comment: Please be more clear with the requirements. Outlook is a client. GMail is more of a mail service. I could use GMail via Outlook.

Answer (score 2):

Email clients (Outlook as well) don't allow executing any JavaScript code in the message body for security reasons. The best what you could do for all mail clients is to paste a hyperlink in the message body and count responses on the server side when users click it.

As for for Outlook, you can use the [MailItem.VotingOptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.votingoptions) property which allows setting a string specifying a delimited string containing the voting options for the mail message.

Voting options on messages are used to give message recipients a list of choices and to track their responses. To create voting options programmatically, set a string that is a semicolon-delimited list of values for the `VotingOptions` property of a `MailItem` object. The values for the `VotingOptions` property will appear under the Vote command in the Respond group in the ribbon of the received message.

```
    using Outlook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;

    private void OrderPizza()
    {
        Outlook.MailItem mail = (Outlook.MailItem)Application.CreateItem(
            Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);
        mail.VotingOptions = “Cheese; Mushroom; Sausage; Combo; Veg Combo;”
        mail.Subject = “Pizza Order”;
        mail.Display(false);
    }
```

Comment: Presumably not fitting into the "should work on gmail" box.

Comment: I've added a part for multi-client environment. See the last part in the post.

Comment: "Outlook doesn't allow executing any JavaScript code in the message body" pretty sure that's true for _all_ email clients.

Comment: The whole Outlook specific stuff just needs to die, it is an awful experience, even when using Outlook. The only part of your answer I would keep is the last paragraph.

Comment: No upvote from me while it contains the Outlook atrocities I'm afraid :)

Comment: Also, don't ask for upvotes, it's crass.

Comment: Agree. Somebody downvoted it.